# Unable to set/use knobs with yapf(A python formatter by google)

Tags: python, formatter, pep8, pep8-checker

I have recently been trying to get familiar with [google/yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf). But somehow, I am unable to set up a **`.style.yapf`** and even **`setup.cfg`**. I am not sure where to place these files. Currently, I am using any/or both files in my current directory but the global settings always override my **`.style.yapf/setup.cfg`** files. Can someone please help me out, I am not getting expected results using their knobs with the sample examples given on [github/yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf#id8)

Answer (score 8):

From [the docs](https://github.com/google/yapf#formatting-style):

> YAPF will search for the formatting style in the following manner:
>
> 1. Specified on the command line
> 2. In the [style] section of a .style.yapf file in either the current directory or one of its parent directories.
> 3. In the [yapf] section of a setup.cfg file in either the current directory or one of its parent directories.
> 4. In the ~/.config/yapf/style file in your home directory.
>
> If none of those files are found, the default style is used (PEP8).

If I use the following Python input for testing:

```py
class Example: # This is an example
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Running `yapf example.py` produces no changes:

```
class Example:  # This is an example
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

But if I create `.style.yapf` in the current directory with the following content:

```
[style]
SPACES_BEFORE_COMMENT=5
BLANK_LINE_BEFORE_NESTED_CLASS_OR_DEF=true
```

And then rerun `yapf example.py`, I get:

```
class Example:     # This is an example

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

If I wanted these changes to apply globaly, I would create instead `~/.config/yapf/style` with the same content.

I could also create a file named `setup.cfg` in the current directory (*or a parent*) with the following content:

```
[yapf]
SPACES_BEFORE_COMMENT=5
BLANK_LINE_BEFORE_NESTED_CLASS_OR_DEF=true
```

Comment: Can i use this with **FormatCode** or **FormatFile**  with the `in_place` parameter set to **True**?

Comment: From [the docs](https://github.com/google/yapf#example-as-a-module) it looks like you have to pass an explicit `style_config` to either of those methods, but if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/google/yapf/blob/master/yapf/__init__.py#L182) you can see how the command line tool does it.